# Bringing trait implementation members into scope using reflection

Tags: scala

I'm using reflection to parse all public variable accessors from classes extending a trait called Component  with the following call:

```
def iterate[T <: Component : TypeTag : ClassTag](component: T) {
  ...
  ru.typeOf[T].members.filter(...)
  ...
}
```

However, this only works if the class type implementing the Component trait is visible during the call:

```
val myComp: MyComponent = new MyComponent()
iterate(myComp) // works

val myComp: Component = new MyComponent()
iterate(myComp) // Doesn't work, no members of MyComponent found in scope
```

One solution would be to define the implementing type in the trait (MyComponent extends Component[MyComponent]), but since I'm digging around with reflection anyway I was wondering if the variables of MyComponent are accessible from behind the trait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get `Type` from `java.lang.Class`. See the example below.

```
╰─$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_65).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)


import scala.reflect._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait Component {
  def parent: Int = 0
}
class MyComponent extends Component {
  def child: Int = 0
}
def printRuntimeMemberNames(component: Component) = {
  val cls = component.getClass
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(cls.getClassLoader)
  val symbol = mirror.staticClass(cls.getName)
  val tpe = symbol.toType
  val members = tpe.members
  val memberNames = members.map(_.name.decodedName.toString)
  println(memberNames.mkString(", "))
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.reflect._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
defined trait Component
defined class MyComponent
printRuntimeMemberNames: (component: Component)Unit

scala> val c: Component = new MyComponent
c: Component = MyComponent@3db7416a

scala> printRuntimeMemberNames(c)
<init>, child, parent, $init$, $asInstanceOf, $isInstanceOf, synchronized, ##, !=, ==, ne, eq, notifyAll, notify, clone, getClass, hashCode, toString, equals, wait, wait, wait, finalize, asInstanceOf, isInstanceOf
```